# Single page application store store user data

Tags: javascript, angularjs, api, browser, single-page-application

I am developing a single page application with angularjs. I am cerating a simple login form to get user data and use it during session. But, if client refreshes the page, user info is removing and user routing to login page again.

I can not use cookie because user validate operation is done by a rest service.

How can I store user data on browser during session. user data should be delete on browser close.

```
    <script>
        var app = angular.module("MyApp", ["ui.router"]);

        app.factory("AuthService", ["$rootScope",function($rootScope){

            return {
                setUserCredentials: function(user){

                    $rootScope.user = { isAuthenticated: true, username: user.username };
                    $rootScope.$emit('handleLogin', { user: user });
                },
                removeUserCreadentials: function(){
                    $rootScope.user = undefined;                            
                },
                isAuthenticated: function(){
                    return $rootScope.user != null;
                },
                getUser: function(){
                    return $rootScope.user;
                }
            }
        }]);

        app.run(function($rootScope, $state, AuthService){
                $rootScope.$on("$stateChangeStart", function(event, toState, toParams, fromState, fromParams){
                    if(toState.authenticate && !AuthService.isAuthenticated()){
                        $state.transitionTo("login");
                        event.preventDefault(); 
                    }
                });
                $rootScope.$on("handleLogin",function(e, args){
                    console.log(e);
                    console.log(args);
                    $state.transitionTo("home");
                });
                $rootScope.$on("handleLogout",function(e, args){
                    console.log(e);
                    console.log(args);
                });
        });

        app.config(function($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider){
            $urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/home');
            $stateProvider.
                state('home',{
                    url: '/home',
                    templateUrl: 'templates/home.html',
                    authenticate: true
                }).
                state('login',{
                    url: '/login',
                    templateUrl: 'templates/login.html',
                    controller: 'LoginController',
                    authenticate: false
                });

            $urlRouterProvider.otherwise("/login");
        });

        app.controller('LoginController', ["$scope", "AuthService", function($scope, AuthService){
            $scope.login = function(){
                if($scope.username == "myuser" && $scope.password == "123456"){
                    AuthService.setUserCredentials({ "username": "myuser" });
                }
            }
        }]);

        app.controller('HomeController', function($scope, $stateParams){

        })

    </script>
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12617103/angualrjs-sustaining-data-on-html-refresh

Answer (score 0):

You can use [sessionStorage](http://www.nczonline.net/blog/2009/07/21/introduction-to-sessionstorage/) new in html5.