# Can't update $rootScope value after submit action

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm a beginner with AngularJS. However, I can't update $rootScope value after submit a form, it's being returned as undefined.

The Controller:

```
app.controller('campaignCtrl', ['$scope', '$rootScope', function($scope, $rootScope) {
  $scope.submit = function() {
    $rootScope.campaign = this.campaign;
  };

}]);
```

And the form:

```
<form class="holder" name="campaignForm"  ng-submit="submit()" >
      <div class="form-group" show-errors>
        <label for="inputDate">Date</label>
        <p class="help-block"><em>Ex: 12/10/2015</em></p>
        <input type="date"  class="form-control" name="inputDate" ng-model="campaign.date" id="inputDate" required>
      </div>
     <button type="submit" class="btn btn-lg btn-default pull-right">Submit</button>
</form>
```

Comment: What is `this` inside that function? I'm betting it's not what you think it is and you're assigning undefined to `$rootScope.campaign`.

Comment: I'm not positive about your use of `this` in that context. Your `campaign` object is being modeled in `$scope`, so most likely you want it to be `$rootScope.campaign = $scope.campaign`

Comment: I've tried this and there was no success with it.. $rootScope.campaign is still undefined ;(

Comment: How are you verifying that it's undefined?

Comment: I'm doing a console.log at the beginning  of the controller `code` app.controller('campaignCtrl', ['$scope', '$rootScope', function($scope, $rootScope) { console.log($rootScope.campaign); }]);`code`

Comment: I don't understand . . . it won't be set at that point right? Doesn't get set till you call submit. Won't it always be undefined there?

Comment: No, after the first submit it would be populated and shared across other controllers..

Comment: Is there a page refresh?

Comment: Well that's why. $rootScope doesn't persist across page refreshes. It's re-initialized on every page load.

Comment: So, how can I share a global variable between controllers and page refreshes?

Comment: Well, I actually already mentioned that in my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I used your code and added a `$watch` on `$rootScope.campaign` and it worked great.

```
.controller('someController', function($scope, $rootScope) {
    $scope.submit = function() {
        $rootScope.campaign = $scope.campaign;
    };

    $rootScope.$watch('campaign', function(newVal, oldVal) {
        if(newVal !== oldVal) {
             console.log("New Val = ");   
            console.log(newVal);
        }
    });
});
```

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/myvy76pr/)

If you are looking for something that persists across a page refresh, that is not `$rootScope`. Look at something like this: [AngualrJS: sustaining data on html refresh](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12617103/angualrjs-sustaining-data-on-html-refresh)

Comment: It worked like a charm!  Now I'll try to persist it across a page refresh. Thanks!

Comment: Can I share the submitted value across page refreshes within a service/factory?

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
$scope.submit = function() {
  $rootScope.campaign = $scope.campaign;
};
```

EDIT:

Try removing `type="submit"` from your button. It could be that your handler doesn't get called because the browser handles the form submission automatically (although you could verify that by putting a log in that function).

```
<button class="btn btn-lg btn-default pull-right">Submit</button>
```

EDIT 2:

Per our conversation via comments: `$rootScope` doesn't persist across requests. You'll need to store it somewhere permanent (like local storage or a cookie) or pass it to the server and then back to the client if you want to hold on to that value. I bet if you add a log inside that `$scope.submit` function, it *will* have a value there.

Comment: Same problem.. It's not updating the global $rooScope campaign variable.. =(

Comment: Ok, I have another idea too.

Comment: Thanks again for your answer! unfortunately, the $rootScope variable isn't being updated yet. Some couple of hours ago I was trying to update an array inside a service from this same submit action and the array wasn't being updated as well..  So, I came to this simple example with $rootScope variables in order to understand why a global value isn't being updated after a form submission..

Comment: How are you checking that it's undefined?

Answer (score 0):

Check this. Your code seems correct except that you are missing closing tag on the input

```
`http://jsfiddle.net/ashishmusale/2001cf6r/`
```

Comment: Inputs don't require closing tags. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/Input

Comment: good too know, I was getting error in jsfiddle, so I suggested. Seems like the code is working fine
I am getting back Object {date: "2015-04-17"} for $rootScope.campaign